# How should I interpret this neural network output?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, neural-network

My code:

```
organelleGroundTruth = selectLabels(gTruth,'organelle');
trainingData = objectDetectorTrainingData(organelleGroundTruth);
acfDetector = trainACFObjectDetector(trainingData,'NegativeSamplesFactor',2);
I = imread('test1.png');   
bboxes = detect(acfDetector,I);
I = insertObjectAnnotation(I,'rectangle',bboxes,'');
imshow(I)
```

I used Image Labeler to label 21 .png images; as shown here:

[image: as shown here]

I exported these into Matlab as "gTruth" (class is ground truth), and the only label name is "organelle" (because all of the white spots are organelles that I want to detect).

I tested the network on this image:

[image: this image.]

This is what the program gave me:

[image: the program gave me].

My first thought is that I labeled not enough images, so the neural network isn't as accurate as it would be with a larger labeled sample size. 
However, I expected each white spot to be inside 1 large rectangle. Instead, the program placed a high number of small rectangles on the objects. 
This is my main question: why are the rectangles so small, and can I tweak that? I think that I can solve the accuracy problem by labeling more images, but I don't know why the rectangles that the program produces are so small.

Comment: It looks like your training images are of much lower quality compared to your test image. Try downsampling your test image to the same size as the training images and run it again.

Comment: @Durkee That helped a lot, thank you! Unfortunately, the rectangles are still quite small. They seem to cover the white spots much more intelligently, but there are many many rectangles covering one white spot - whereas I was hoping for one rectangle to contain one white spot. Do you know where I could change this?

Comment: Please format your Markdown to include the actual images, not just links to them.  Thanks!

Comment: @MaxvonHippel I'm afraid I don't know how - are the links a problem?

Comment: I just suggested an edit to fix it, but for future reference do it like this `![doesn't matter][url]` (as opposed to a link `[label][url]` without the `!`)

Comment: @MaxvonHippel I'll definitely remember that for the future, thanks! Do you have any suggestions for the question itself? I have a feeling that the issue may be the difference in sizes between the training images and the input image, because I labeled the training images pixel by pixel. I'm not familiar with this stuff, though, so I'm really not sure.

Comment: I think we need to know more about your code.  There could be a variable (some sort of `sigma` or `threshold` or `sensitivity` or something) you tweak to say how many matches to look for.  Also, were the training images the same resolution as the image you test on?

Comment: The code in the original post is actually the entire script - so if there is such a variable, I would have to dig deeper into the built-in functions that I used. I'm honestly very new to this stuff, so I'm not sure how to check the resolution of the images. I know that their sizes (after using "imread()") were very, very different. The test image matrix is ~ 10 times bigger in each dimension. I used "imresize()" before testing, but maybe this is not enough?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I accidentally called this a neural network - it is an object detector.

After more reading/tinkering, I've come to the conclusion that I need far, far more samples. Matlab's built in object detectors need thousands of sample images (particularly for samples so small in size) to be accurate.